# RCTSinglelineTextInputView.h file not found (RNTextInputMask.m)

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I want to build my react-native app in xCode I get an error.

```
 RCTSinglelineTextInputView.h file not found
```

in file *(RNTextInputMask.m)*

This is connected to https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask, I've done two addtional steps from the guide.